# task adjust accordingly to an hours timeline grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

hi i am working on a UI which needs the task performed at specific time and date can be automatically adjusted in the hour timeline provided at the top according to the time assigned to it.If someone can please guide me how to do it it will be of great help . you can take as an example of 24 hour timeline and flights that are assigned in different timing on that day thanks in advance

Comment: please show your code what you try for that

Comment: [refer this link please][1]


  [1]: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZJR4sxDu0hHDKPICxcl5?p=preview

Comment: why you not using $interval ?

Comment: i am actually a newbie can you please elaborate

Answer (score 0):

I'm not doing your homeworks, but i'll help you start.
First create the date when the task should be executed, like that:

```
var d = new Date(2015, 10, 18, 10, 30, 35);  //year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds
```

Then create the task:

```
var myTask = function(){
    alert("executing task");
}
```

The main function will compare the date you provided with the actual date, and if it's equal (or less) it will execute the task

```
function createTask(date, callback){
    if(date && callback){
        var interv = setInterval(function(){ 
            var nd = new Date();
            if(date <= nd){
                callback();
                clearInterval(interv);
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

So call the function with your parameters, and that's it.

```
createTask(d, myTask);
```

In [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/8vx7v5n9/5/) a task will be executed today at 10:30. Edit date to make your tests